# Python 2: Vague syntax Error on "continue" command

Tags: syntax-error, python-2.x, continue

I am working on a script that creates a map in ESRI arcmap 10.8. I currently have only created the script to create the geodatabase and ask for the base information required to create the map. The script asks for information and then loops to ask the user if the information is correct.

It was working fine until (I think) when I changed the print function on line 27 from    **), wksp**   to     **) + wksp**   (it just looks nicer).

Now I am getting an error that says:

File "h:/mystuff/python code/ExA_temp_code/variable_test_string.py", line 29
continue
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
PS C:\Users\kvidal.IDIR>

Here is my code. Please keep in mind that I am still new to python and this script is not cleaned up yet in my raw_input lines. I wrote 29 on the left side of line 29 to find it easily. I am using visual studio code.

```
    import time, os.path, arcpy
    from os import path
    #   Asking for the information that I will use in the sql query 
    #   that will be used to create the tenure feature class
    print("""NOTE: Please make sure your workspace path goes to your working
    folder. Use file explorer or something that allows you to copy the path then
    paste the path below. This will prevent you typing an incorrect path.\n""")
    #   Pause the program for 2s to allow user to realize that there is 
    #   something to read before the input.
    time.sleep(2)
    
    #   Setting the variables
    wksp = raw_input("Please enter the path to the working folder. >> ")
    arcpy.env.workspace= r"wksp"
    print("You have input as your file path: ")+ wksp 
    chk_wksp = raw_input("Please check your path and confirm y/n. >>")
    while True:
        while True:
            if chk_wksp in ('y', 'n'):
                break
            chk_wksp = raw_input("That is not a valid response Please enter y/n. >> ")
        if chk_wksp == 'y':
            print("Thank you")
            break
        else:
            wksp = raw_input("Please re-enter the path. >> ")
            print("Is this the correct path? >> ") + wksp
            chk_wksp = raw_input("Please confirm y/n: >>" 
29          continue
    
    gdb = raw_input("Please enter the new geodatabase name. >> ")
    arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(wksp, gdb, "10")
    
    gdb = raw_input("What do you want to name the geodatabase? >> ")
    permitType = raw_input("Is this a road permit y/n. >> ")
    fileNo = raw_input("What is the file number you are looking up? >> ")
    
    #   here I am saying if this is a road permit (permitType = y)
    #   then ask for the section names. if it is not a road permit
    #   then ask for block names
    if permitType is "y":
        secNo = raw_input("Please enter the road sections divided by a space. >> ")
    else:
        secNo = raw_input("Please enter the cut blocks divided by a space. >> ")
    
    #   Here I am splitting the list into individual strings for the sql
    #   sequence I will use for the select too.
    input_list = secNo.split()
    
    #   Here I am confirming that the information is correct.
    print ("Please confirm that this is correct. >> "),fileNo, " ",input_list
    yORn = raw_input("Is this correct y/n? >> ")
    #   This is where I want to look at their answer and provide 
    #   an appropriate answer.
    while True:
        while True:
            if yORn in ('y', 'n'):
                break
            print("invalid input")
            yORn = raw_input("Please select \"y\" if correct or \"n\" if incorrect.")
        if yORn == 'n':
            fileNo = raw_input("What is the file number you are looking up? >> ")
            if permitType is "y":
                secNo = raw_input("Please enter the road sections divided by a space. >> ")
                input_list = secNo.split()
                print ("Please confirm that this is correct. >> "),fileNo, " ",input_list
                yORn = raw_input("Is this correct y/n? >> ")
            else:
                secNo = raw_input("Please enter the cut blocks divided by a space. >> ")
                input_list = secNo.split()           
                print ("Please confirm that this is correct. >> "),fileNo, " ",input_list
                yORn = raw_input("Is this correct y/n? >> ")
            continue
        else:
            print("Thank you, I will begin map generation. ")
            print ("...")
            print("...")
            print("...")
            break
```

Comment: hi, it appears the line before the `continue` is missing a close parentheses.

Comment: The problem is the unclosed parenthesis above. I am voting to close this as a mere typo

Comment: It's *always* a missing close parenthesis on the line above.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax error is line 28:

```
chk_wksp = raw_input("Please confirm y/n: >>"
continue
```

->

```
chk_wksp = raw_input("Please confirm y/n: >>")
continue
```

You should consider using Python3 since Python2 is end of life

Comment: Thank you. I stared at this code for ages and it was a bracket.